# google app script- data not printing corresponding to their keys

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

in my API, i have few things like suppose name of companies and am printing them in sorted form after fetching from api but their crrosponding URL'sarent getting printed corrosponding to the name of companies
i.e, i have sorted the keys in the object and printed them in ascending order but the values of those keys arent printing corrosponding to those keys

the URL's are getting printed in the same sequence as its there in API but the keys, i have sorted them to print in accending order
  am not able to print the values corrosponding to their keys from the object

the function is here:

```
function fetchFromApi() {
  var url = '<My API from where am fetching the data>';
  var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var urlResult = JSON.parse(urlResponse);
  var key = Object.keys(urlResult);
  var tempArr = [];
  for (var x in urlResult) {
  var value = urlResult[x];
  value = value.replace(/\\/g, '');
  tempArr.push([value])
  }
  inputSheet.getRange(2,6,tempArr.length,1).setValues(tempArr);
  printData();
}

function printData() {
  keys.sort();
  key = [];
  for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  key[i] = [];
  key[i][0] = keys[i];
  }
  var range = inputSheet.getRange(2, 1, key.length, 1);
  range.setValues(key);
  }
```

Comment: It is not clear where `printData` function is called.

Comment: It's called in Fetchfromapi function..

Comment: Could you please share your url (if external)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing the keys and values to the sheet and then sort using `range.sort(col)`.

In the `for` loop in fetchFromApi(), after `tempArr.push([value])` do `key.push([x])`. At the end of the loop, write `key` to column 1 and `tempArr` to column 6 of `inputSheet`. Then, you can do

```
var range = inputSheet.getRange(2, 1, key.length, 6);
range.sort(1);
```

which sorts everything between columns 1 and 6 in ascending order according to the value of the keys in column 1. See below for the reference on `range.sort(sortSpecObj)`.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj